# Connect Two Devices using bluetooth Android?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I want to connect two devices using bluetooth programming in android, please guide me
and I do request you to not refer to Android Documentation, it is really very poor written, so just explain in your own words

Comment: I don't think the doc is poor written. Taking a look at the developer guide won't harm anybody.

Comment: @Mister, I know it is your idea, but go and read the apple documentation, it is awesome, and as compared to that i said that android doc is poorly written.

Comment: I think your own patience and ability to read documentation is the problem, because Android's Bluetooth documentation is very good. They provide you with the Bluetooth Chat example, and their documentation describes how it works very thoroughly. The Bluetooth Chat example is an application that already does exactly as you're asking, and its source code is well documented. There are also about a billion Android Bluetooth questions on StackOverflow, many of which I've provided detailed answers to. I'm not sure how much easier you want it to be.

Comment: @Veer Yeah, just read the iOS bluetooth API doc and, Oh wait... there isn't XD

Comment: @Mister and Trevor, I just want to say that see the structure of iOS bluetooth programming, the pairing, the sending and recieving is structured, but here I can't find any structure at all, and have to concentrate more as compared to iOS programming,

Comment: Oh really, I was really unaware that it is not poorly written, well just tell me that what happens if you click the "No Paired Device", the first row, if there is no device, then simply a crash, so is it the best google example?

Comment: and the pairing, as you will just click pairing, it is go to the time line above bar, and hides there, why?

Comment: The sample apps are merely a prototype, there is almost no robustness built into them as they're created as a source for beginners to learn.

Comment: @Justin, O really, that is why for creating a simple TabBar based app, and opening multiple activities within same tab, you have to waste your time, this is really what Android has given their prototype.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Bluetooth Chat Application**

- Have you looked through the [Bluetooth Chat Application](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html)?

I have found that the sample applications fill in a lot of the gaps in the documentation, and is generally my first source of inspiration when investigating an android feature.

**Edit**

If you've downloaded the SDK these sample apps are usually bundled with the SDK.  For me this app is found under.

- \android-sdk-windows\samples\android-7\BluetoothChat

**Update**

- [DeviceListActivity](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/src/com/example/android/BluetoothChat/DeviceListActivity.html)

It lists any paired devices and devices detected in the area after discovery. When a device is chosen by the user, the MAC address of the device is sent back to the parent Activity in the result Intent.

Seems pretty straight forward, what part are you having difficulty with?

Comment: I have seen this, but still have query that how it is adding and making pairs, can you u explain it a bit Sir, please,

Comment: Just I want brief intro that how actually I should work with it?